# Laravel 5.1 Logger Timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, laravel-5.1

Is there a way I can change the timezone for the Laravel 5.1 logger? I've seen previous discussions where they extended the Monolog class and updated the Service Provider, but that was for an older version of Laravel and it doesn't look like the `LogServiceProvider` is used anymore.

I see there's a `timezone` key in the `app.php` file, but I don't want the whole system to change. I just want to update the timezone for the logs, and keep the rest of the system in UTC.

Comment: Why not make your own provider to extend the `Monolog` class and change the timezone that way?

Comment: I don't think I have a problem extending the class and setting the timezone, but I'm not exactly sure how to make the system use that extended class instead of the `Monolog` class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just saw your reply, I've figured it out and it's really simple. Create a new service provider and register it in `config/app.php` then add the following line to the `boot` method.

```
Logger::setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('PST'));
```

Make sure you include the `Logger` class at the top of your service provider.

You may set the timezone to whichever one you'd like from this list, http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Can't believe it was that simple. I'll need to do some more reading. Thanks again.

Comment: This worked for me in Lumen 6.0, however I used Log::setTimezone  instead of Logger::setTimezone.  I just created a new service provider class called app/Providers/LogTimeZoneServiceProvider.php, included the suggested code in the boot() method, and added it to the providers array in bootstrap/app.php